# how can I move RAID-1 hard disks from one Debian to another?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, raid1

I have a computer with Debian. On this computer I have two hard disks which are configured as RAID-1, which are mounted as "/" (as a root). I want to move these disks (without wiping, formatting them) to another computer with Debian - and have this other Debian configured in such way that these disks are mounted (as RAID-1) to some directory (for instance, as /mnt/something) during the start. How should I do this? Should I move some configuration files from the old computer to the new computer?

Here is some information about my system:

```
  $ cat /proc/mdstat 
  Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
  md0 : active raid1 sda3[2] sdb3[0]
        1943618560 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        bitmap: 1/15 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

  md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda1[3] sdb1[2]
        4877312 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

  unused devices: <none>

  $ grep '^ARRAY' /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
  ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=0841a7e6:a65d70c0:03852c15:346f5bb1 name=gcw:1
  ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=950ac803:b9a6ff13:08626696:5f9811f5 name=gcw:0

  $ mount | grep -v '^cgroup'
  sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
  proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
  udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1956312k,nr_inodes=489078,mode=755)
  devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
  tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=403736k,mode=755)
  /dev/md0 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
  securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
  tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
  tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
  tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
  pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
  bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
  systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13127)
  hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
  debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
  mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
  sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
  binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
  tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=403736k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
  gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Comment: Are the disks configured as RAID1 or the partitions on those disks? Please add the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` on the source machine to your question. Also the result of `grep '^ARRAY' /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, and finally the output of `mount | grep -v '^cgroup'`

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the lines from `mdadm.conf` to the new host. If the new host has MD devices, too, then you may have to change the numbers (md0 => md2).

Of course, you also have to make the respective entries in `/etc/fstab` (with the new MD numbers or better the UUIDs).

Comment: I tried it and it works.